# C++ MFC: Shortcut/Accelerator in Menu after \t does not apper

Tags: c++, windows, menu, mfc, desktop-application

I am using Visual C++ 2019 with MFC.
At the menu editor, local menu of the menu item, Properties Page, Caption: I wrote for example:

Save All\tCtrl+Shift+S

I see this in the menu editor, but in the program "Crtl+Shift+S" does not appear. I tried when there was an event handler, and when did not have an event handler. This is independent from existing the event handler. For example, the menu items what are already exist are the same:

New\tCtrl+N

How can I display the Ctrl+Shift+S ? Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the Ctrl+Shift+S to the accelerator table? If using the more recent `CWinAppEx` class (and others, maybe), the main menu is automatically updated to add accelerator shortcut labels.

Comment: Thank you, this resolved Save All, but did not resolve other menu items, for example: Encoding for Open\tF2, Redo\tCtrl+Y, Select All\tCtrl+A.

Comment: Well, did you add each of those to the accelerator table?

Comment: Yes, naturally!

Comment: If you have run your application even once, and then modified the menus, shortcuts or accelerators, which usually does happen during development, you may need to reset the data stored in the registry. From the toolbar, select Add or Remove Buttons->Customize->Options->Reset my usage data. If this doesn't fix it, try deleting the whole application tree in the registry. It is typically under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\CompanyName\AppName, or HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Local AppWizard-Generated Applications\AppName, if you haven't changed the registry path.

Comment: Did you add it to the right menu? We don't have much context. In a MDI app there is a "app menu" and a "doc menu". So could it be that you are checking the wrong menu? I have these menu accelerators in my MFC app.

Comment: I added to both menus. There was accelerator only for IDR_MAINFRAME. I created IDR_IDETYPE (this is the name among the menus: IDR_MAINFRAME: if there is no document opened, IDR_IDETYPE is there is document opened).

Comment: Thank you. The resolution: to the command prompt: IDE /Unregister

Comment: At Stack Overflow, I can accept only answers. I can not accept a comment.

Comment: Did you `InitKeyboardManager();` ? From the moment you do it, what you say in the `MENUITEM` entries with `\tSome Key` is overridden by the accelerator table. And the accelerator table can be overridden by user customization. And there are ways to override user customization also.

Comment: Yes, In CIDEApp::InitInstance(): automatic generated code be MFC (solution wizard: a program template). As I wrote, I solved so: to the command prompt: IDE /Unregister